# How to add an emoji tag to the page's title tag?

Tags: html, tags, title, emoji

I'm using [this](https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/) library to add emojis to my page. It works great. But, now I want to add an emoji the page's title but it doesn't work.

The emoji tag looks like this:

```
<i class="em em-rocket">
```

If I do this:

```
  <title>Seif Rocks <i class="em em-rocket"></i></title>
```

It looks like this without showing the emoji:

```
Seif Rocks <i class="em em-rocket"></i>
```

Is it possible to add an HTML tag to the title tag?